# Count next X days without Sunday using Laravel carbon

Tags: laravel, validation, datetime, php-carbon

I am developing a subscription based application using Laravel. I want to change the state of the user to *expire* after 75 days of subscribing to the package. I want to exclude Sundays from these 75 days.

Consider a scenario where user's account is verified today and he has only access to the premium functionalities for 75 days(without Sundays). After the 75 days, the user needs to resubscribe to get access to the premium functionalities of the application.

I will then set up a middleware which will check if the user's subscription is expired or not.

I have two scenarios to check for expiration:

1. Save the expiration date column in the `users` table.
2. Verify each user's request based on `verified_at` (datetime) column and prevent premium access if the user subscription is over more than 75 days without Sundays.

I want to achieve this using [Laravel Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) or any other alternative library/functionality.

After 75 Days from Today(11 June) is August 25 ‍♂️
After 75 Days from Today(11 June - Excluding Sundays) is September 07

Reference: https://getcalc.com/75business-days-after-today.htm

Comment: News about my answer?

Comment: @Berto99 Thank you for your answer and your explanation, I have found some problems when using the solution you provided. Consider, I created an account today on Friday 12th June which is 5th day, then the `$period_in_days` will be 86 and if I get the date after the 86 days from the Friday is September 06 whereas if I get 75 days from Friday EXCLUDING SUNDAYS, I will get September 08. I have validated using https://getcalc.com/75business-days-after-today.htm See my answer, how I solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can count next 75 days excluding Sundays using the following PHP function

```php
function Next75Days($StartingDate){
        // Count Next 75 Days excluding Sundays
        $Days = 75;

        $d = new DateTime($StartingDate);
        $t = $d->getTimestamp();

        // Loop for 75 days
        for($i=0; $i<$Days; $i++){

            // Add 1 day to timestamp
            $addDay = 86400;

            // Get date of next day
            $nextDay = date('w', ($t+$addDay));

            // if it's Sunday, do $i--1
            if($nextDay == 0) {
                $i--;
            }

            // modify timestamp, add 1 day
            $t = $t+$addDay;
        }

        $d->setTimestamp($t);

        return $d->format('d M Y');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `75` is fixed, than you could easily calculate the number of Sundays in the period, and so then you just need adding those days to the `75`:

```
$period_in_days = 75;
if($user->verified_at->dayOfWeek > 2)
    $period_in_days += 11;
else 
    $period_in_days += 10;
```

The point is, in 75 days there could either 10 or 11 Sundays, and so in order to decide whether there are 10 or 11, we need to check which day is the first day.
Let's say is Monday the first day, so the 75 days should looks like this

```
1 - Monday
2 - Tuesday
...
71 - Monday
72 - Tuesday
73 - Wednesday
74 - Thursday
75 - Friday
```

Let's say is Tuesday the first day, so the 75 days should looks like this

```
1 - Tuesday
2 - Wednesday
...
71 - Tuesday
72 - Wednesday
73 - Thursday
74 - Friday
75 - Saturday
```

Let's say is Wednesday the first day, so the 75 days should looks like this

```
1 - Wednesday
2 - Thursday
...
71 - Wednesday
72 - Thursday
73 - Friday
74 - Saturday
75 - Sunday
```

So if the first day is not neither `Monday` and `Tuesday`, then there will be `11` Sundays (10 + the 1 that appears in the  [71- 75]), otherwise there will be only 10 Sundays

Comment: Do you mind explaining this more. Also, 86 and 85 days from today are not showing the exact date as 75 days from now excluding Sundays.

Comment: @Muhaddis please check the answer